# Trying to Make Sense of Knockout.js Custom binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

**So I am working with Knockout Custom Bindings and I have the following code:**

```
<input type="radio" class="radio" data-bind="custombind: custombind"/>
<input type="text" class="text" data-bind="custombind: custombind"/>
```

--js--

```
var viewModel = {
        custombind: ko.observable(true)
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

ko.bindingHandlers.custombind = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) 
    {
        alert($(element).attr('class'));
    }
}
```

Maybe I am misunderstanding how custom bindings work, but I would expect this to return the class names of any element with the "*custombind*" data-bind. Currently nothing seems to be happening. Any advice as to where I am going wrong would be appreciated. Thanks

**--fiddle--**

http://jsfiddle.net/tU4Fg/16/

--**reference**--

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough this is not explicity stated in the documentation but all the custom bindings should be defined **before** calling `ko.applyBindings`.

Otherwise KO won't know what to do  with your custom binding when parsing the `data-bind` attributes.

So the following code works fine:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.custombind = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, 
                   viewModel, bindingContext) 
    {
        alert($(element).attr('class'));
    }
}

var viewModel = {
    custombind: ko.observable(true)
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfaDe/).

Comment: I did not know that! Thanks for the help, I have been trying to figure this out for sometime now and never stopped to think that it might be a scope issue. I just figured I was messing up something else.